# bash stop pipe if command fails

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Consider following script

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eux
set -o pipefail


function will_fail() {
    echo 'I do not work because of xyz' >&2
    exit 1
}

will_fail | gzip > test.gz
```

This will create a file `test.gz`

Is there a way with pipes to stop at `will_fail` and not create `test.gz`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the output file is created before the pipeline is started, there is no way to prevent the output file from being created.

So the only chance you have is to remove the file again in case the pipeline fails.

A `kshism` (the `ERR` trap) that is supported in `bash` may be used if you are looking for a script solution.

In this case, I strongly recommend to use

```
set -o noclobber
```

To prevent the file to be clobbered in case it exists before already.

So the recommended code would look this way:

```
set -o noclobber

trap 'rm -rf test.gz' ERR

some_cmd | gzip > test.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

```bash
if ! will_fail | gzip >test.gz; then
        rm -f test.gz
fi
```

This does not prevent the creation of the file (the redirection will create the file before the pipeline executes), but it removes the file if the pipeline fails (assuming `pipefail` is set, as it is in the example).

Comment: does this behave the same way as `will_fail | gzip >test.gz || rm -f test.gz`?

Comment: @SpinUp__ADavis I believe that is true.